# How to remove words starts with : sign and ends with : sign, not a full sentence in c#

Tags: c#

I want to remove the words having : sign (Like :word:) in its both side.I have already use a regular expression to remove all between two : sign. But i need to remove just single words exists between two : sign, not a full sentence (Like :I like to play cricket:).

```
string txt = "Hello, i :want: to remove :some word from: my text";
var output = Regex.Replace(txt, @" ?\:.*?\:", " ");
```

Expected Output:

> Hello, i to remove some word from my text

Comment: Would \:\w\: work for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the problem is your regex. try this:

```
 var output = Regex.Replace(txt, @":([A-Za-z0-9]*):", "");
```

Comment: I was about to write `var output = Regex.Replace(txt, @" ?\:\S*?\:", " ");`

Comment: This will give error at runtime since you didn't escape the literal : in it.

Comment: @TanveerBadar - `:` doesn't need to be escaped.

Comment: the `@` symbol escapes those characters`.

Comment: @arlanschouwstra - The `@` symbol doesn't escape the characters. It just tells the the C# compiler to interpret the string verbatim. It's nothing to do with escaping `Regex` literals.

Answer (score 2):

In your regex you're using `.*` this matches any character except newline. Instead I assume you would like any non-whitespace character. In regex this would be `\S`, so in total you would get:

```
string txt = "Hello, i :want: to remove :some word from: my text";
var output = Regex.Replace(txt, @" ?\:\S*?\:", " ");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use character class for matching words in your regex.

```
"\\:\\w\\:"
```

This will match words surrounded by : on both sides and nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest this one:

```
var output = Regex.Replace(txt, @":\w+:", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find all the words  having : sign in its both side But it should not have space

```
string txt = "Hello, i :want: to remove :some word from: my :test:";
var output = Regex.Replace(txt, @" \:\w+\b(?! )\:", " ");
```